# Checking to see if an NSString contains characters from a different NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, nspredicate

I am looking for a way to compare two strings and see if the second string contains a character (letter, number, other) listed in the first, let me explain:

For example: Imagine a password with only digits and "*" are allowed:
Reference chain  (1): "*0123456789"  `NSString` format, no `NSArray`
Work chain (2) = "156/15615=211" `NSString` format,

How do I know that my chain 2 contains 2 characters (/=) which are not in my chain 1?

To simplify the management letters allowed, I do not want to use `NSArray` to manage a chain for example a function call:

```
BOOL unauthorized_letter_found = check(work_chain, reference_chain);
```

You it must go through "for", `NSPredicate`, etc. ?

PS: I'm on MAC OS, not iOS so I can not use `NSRegularExpression`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use an `NSPredicate`, you can do:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES '[0-9*]+'"];
if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:@"0*2481347*"]) {
  NSLog(@"passes!");
} else {
  NSLog(@"fails!");
}
```

This is using `NSPredicate`'s built-in regular expression matching stuff. :)

Answer (score 9):

You could go with character sets, e.g. using [`-rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) to check for the presence of forbidden characters:

```
NSCharacterSet *notAllowed = [[NSCharacterSet 
    characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*0123456789"] invertedSet];
NSRange range = [inputString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notAllowed];
BOOL unauthorized = (range.location != NSNotFound);
```

Comment: NSRange range = [inputString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:allowed];

Should `allowed` be changed to `notAllowed`?

Comment: Ahh terrific.  And great answer also, +1