# NSPredicate to test if NSString contains a character from another NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nspredicate

I'm trying to see if an `NSString` contains any character from a predefined string (any of A, B, or C).

I know I can do this:

```
NSCharacterSet *abc = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"ABC"];
NSRange range = [sequence rangeOfCharacterFromSet: abc];
BOOL result = (range.location != NSNotFound);
```

This results in YES if the incoming string contains at least one A, B, or C.

I'm trying to see if I can use an `NSPredicate` as an alternative, so I've been playing with it (eg see also here: [Checking to see if an NSString contains characters from a different NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5759839/checking-to-see-if-an-nsstring-contains-characters-from-a-different-nsstring)), but I always get a result of NO:

```
NSPredicate *abcPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF matches 'ABC'"];
result = [stedPredicate evaluateWithObject: myString];
```

I tried replacing matches with contains, but that didn't help.

Also tried:

```
NSPredicate *stedPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF LIKE 'ABC'"];
```

How can I change the predicate for it to work?

Comment: this will check if the string contains a substring like `ABC` rather than get any of the character in "ABC"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a string contains any of the characters A, B, or C you can use
the regular expression *bracket expression* "[ABC]":

```
NSPredicate *abcPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES %@", @".*[ABC].*"];
BOOL result = [abcPredicate evaluateWithObject: myString];
```